# What microarchitecture are packages on apt/yum typically built/tuned for?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, source, cpu-architecture

I'm just learning a bit about lower-level languages and I've noticed that gcc you can specify -march and -mtune parameters to optimise the software for particular CPU families.

But I've also found people saying that [building a program from source won't make it noticeably faster than downloading the binary](https://askubuntu.com/a/158661/146215). Surely being able to have the software optimised for the CPU in your system would provide a notable speed boost, especially in software like `ffmpeg` which uses fairly microarchitecture-dependent features such as AVX?

What I'm wondering is, are the binaries on package managers somehow optimised for multiple microarchitectures? Does the package manager download binaries specific to my system's microarchitecture?

Comment: Looking at the gcc documentation, it seems likely that most distributed amd64 binaries use an march of "x86-64" and an mtune of "generic". This should allow the application to run on any amd64 CPU, and will tune the assembly to run fastest on the most common processors.

This suggests that depending on the processor it may be possible to significantly improve performance by compiling from source, either by allowing the compiler to use microarchitecture-specific instructions or by improving the tuning for less-common processors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distribution packages are built with reference to a pre-determined baseline (see [Debian’s architecture baselines](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo#Architecture_baselines) for example). Thus, in Debian, `amd64` packages target generic x86-64 CPUs, with SSE2 but not SSE3 or later; `i386` packages target generic i686 CPUs, without MMX or SSE. In general, the compiler defaults are used, so tuning might evolve as the compiler itself evolves.

*However* packages where CPU-specific optimisations provide significant benefit can be built to take advantage of newer CPUs. This is done by providing multiple implementations rather than relying on compiler optimisations, and choosing between them at runtime: the packaged software detects the running CPU and adjusts the code paths it uses to take advantage of it (see `ffmpeg`’s `libswscale/x86/swscale.c` for example). On some architectures, [`ld.so`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html#NOTES) itself helps with this: it can automatically load an optimised library if it’s available, *e.g.* on an `i386`-architecture system running on an SSE-capable CPU.

Most if not all package managers are oblivious to all this; they download a given architecture’s package and install it, without regard for the CPU running the system.